# How to access JSON value if multiple keys have exact name?

Tags: json

Assume I have JSON like:

```
let myJSON = {
      "id" : 001,
      "firstName" : "John",
      "firstName" : "Jane", 
      "lastName" : "Doe"
    }
```

If I call myJSON.firstname, it will return "Jane". My question is, How to get data "John" instead of "Jane"?

Comment: how are you creating your JSON object? - it seems like invalid JSON to me as you cannot have the same attribute twice in the same object.

Answer (score 2):

The second `firstname` overwrites the first one. So as soon as you declare or assign it to a variable you wouldn't get it at all as it is overwritten. You can try this in your developer tools and see that there is just one key/value pair present for that key. See also my screenshot demonstrating:

[image]

If you get your object by string from somewhere else there is a possibility to filter out those duplicates or create an array instead of duplicates. But I think that wasn't the original question. This isn't strictly prohibited but I assume even thought it is not a valid JSON by means of what you want. What do you want to achieve with this or where does this come from?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. JavaScript objects does not allow have properties with the same name.

You should change property name from API side.